# Ubuntu 18.04 prompts an error when installing mysql. The following message is displayed. Does any kind-hearted person know how to solve it

Tags: mysql

This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.38, use `--force` if you still need to run mysql_upgrade

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-06-28 09:40:23 CST; 4ms ago
  Process: 13996 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=127)
  Process: 13974 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
```

---

##### After using the `systemctl status mysql.service` command, the following is displayed:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-06-28 09:40:24 CST; 11min ago
  Process: 14157 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=127)
  Process: 14136 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 28 09:40:24 siashcsitd03674 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 28 09:40:24 siashcsitd03674 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 28 09:40:24 siashcsitd03674 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jun 28 09:40:24 siashcsitd03674 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 28 09:40:24 siashcsitd03674 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 28 09:40:24 siashcsitd03674 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

---

##### After using the journalctl -xe command, the following is displayed

```
Jun 28 09:52:59 siashcsitd03674 audit: PROCTITLE proctitle=736C6565700031
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit[24688]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=56 success=yes exit=19051 a0=1200011 a1=0 a2=0 a3=7ff9dd854a10 items=0 ppid=24535 pid=24688 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PROCTITLE proctitle=62617368002D63007768696C6520747275653B20646F20736C65657020313B68656164202D76202D6E2038202F70726F632F6D656D696E666F3B2068656164202D76202D6E2032202F7
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit[19051]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=5631de56ba30 a1=5631de5690f0 a2=5631de5680b0 a3=8 items=2 ppid=24688 pid=19051 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: EXECVE argc=5 a0="head" a1="-v" a2="-n" a3="8" a4="/proc/meminfo"
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: CWD cwd="/root"
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PATH item=0 name="/usr/bin/head" inode=393314 dev=fc:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PATH item=1 name="/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" inode=3417 dev=fc:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=00000000000000
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PROCTITLE proctitle=68656164002D76002D6E0038002F70726F632F6D656D696E666F
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit[24688]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=56 success=yes exit=19052 a0=1200011 a1=0 a2=0 a3=7ff9dd854a10 items=0 ppid=24535 pid=24688 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PROCTITLE proctitle=62617368002D63007768696C6520747275653B20646F20736C65657020313B68656164202D76202D6E2038202F70726F632F6D656D696E666F3B2068656164202D76202D6E2032202F7
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit[19052]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=5631de56dd00 a1=5631de56f000 a2=5631de5680b0 a3=5631de55f010 items=2 ppid=24688 pid=19052 auid=0 uid=0 gi
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: EXECVE argc=10 a0="head" a1="-v" a2="-n" a3="2" a4="/proc/stat" a5="/proc/version" a6="/proc/uptime" a7="/proc/loadavg" a8="/proc/sys/fs/file-nr" a9="/proc/sys/kernel/
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: CWD cwd="/root"
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PATH item=0 name="/usr/bin/head" inode=393314 dev=fc:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PATH item=1 name="/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" inode=3417 dev=fc:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=00000000000000
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PROCTITLE proctitle=68656164002D76002D6E0032002F70726F632F73746174002F70726F632F76657273696F6E002F70726F632F757074696D65002F70726F632F6C6F6164617667002F70726F632F73797
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit[24688]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=56 success=yes exit=19053 a0=1200011 a1=0 a2=0 a3=7ff9dd854a10 items=0 ppid=24535 pid=24688 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PROCTITLE proctitle=62617368002D63007768696C6520747275653B20646F20736C65657020313B68656164202D76202D6E2038202F70726F632F6D656D696E666F3B2068656164202D76202D6E2032202F7
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit[19053]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=5631de56c440 a1=5631de5690f0 a2=5631de5680b0 a3=8 items=2 ppid=24688 pid=19053 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: EXECVE argc=5 a0="tail" a1="-v" a2="-n" a3="16" a4="/proc/net/dev"
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: CWD cwd="/root"
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PATH item=0 name="/usr/bin/tail" inode=393480 dev=fc:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PATH item=1 name="/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" inode=3417 dev=fc:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=00000000000000
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PROCTITLE proctitle=7461696C002D76002D6E003136002F70726F632F6E65742F646576
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit[24688]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=56 success=yes exit=19054 a0=1200011 a1=0 a2=0 a3=7ff9dd854a10 items=0 ppid=24535 pid=24688 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PROCTITLE proctitle=62617368002D63007768696C6520747275653B20646F20736C65657020313B68656164202D76202D6E2038202F70726F632F6D656D696E666F3B2068656164202D76202D6E2032202F7
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit[19054]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=5631de56dd00 a1=5631de56dda0 a2=5631de5680b0 a3=8 items=2 ppid=24688 pid=19054 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: EXECVE argc=2 a0="df" a1="-l"
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: CWD cwd="/root"
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PATH item=0 name="/bin/df" inode=29956 dev=fc:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 cap_fve
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PATH item=1 name="/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" inode=3417 dev=fc:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=00000000000000
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PROCTITLE proctitle=6466002D6C
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit[24688]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=56 success=yes exit=19055 a0=1200011 a1=0 a2=0 a3=7ff9dd854a10 items=0 ppid=24535 pid=24688 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PROCTITLE proctitle=62617368002D63007768696C6520747275653B20646F20736C65657020313B68656164202D76202D6E2038202F70726F632F6D656D696E666F3B2068656164202D76202D6E2032202F7
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit[19055]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=5631de56c440 a1=5631de56dd20 a2=5631de5680b0 a3=8 items=2 ppid=24688 pid=19055 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: EXECVE argc=1 a0="who"
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: CWD cwd="/root"
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PATH item=0 name="/usr/bin/who" inode=393522 dev=fc:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 c
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PATH item=1 name="/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" inode=3417 dev=fc:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=00000000000000
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PROCTITLE proctitle="who"
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit[24688]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=56 success=yes exit=19056 a0=1200011 a1=0 a2=0 a3=7ff9dd854a10 items=0 ppid=24535 pid=24688 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PROCTITLE proctitle=62617368002D63007768696C6520747275653B20646F20736C65657020313B68656164202D76202D6E2038202F70726F632F6D656D696E666F3B2068656164202D76202D6E2032202F7
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit[19056]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=5631de56bae0 a1=5631de56c880 a2=5631de5680b0 a3=0 items=2 ppid=24688 pid=19056 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: EXECVE argc=2 a0="sleep" a1="1"
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: CWD cwd="/root"
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PATH item=0 name="/bin/sleep" inode=30018 dev=fc:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 cap_
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PATH item=1 name="/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" inode=3417 dev=fc:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=00000000000000
Jun 28 09:53:00 siashcsitd03674 audit: PROCTITLE proctitle=736C6565700031
Jun 28 09:53:01 siashcsitd03674 audit[31150]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=56 success=yes exit=19057 a0=1200011 a1=0 a2=0 a3=7f96ec4dea10 items=0 ppid=31149 pid=31150 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid
Jun 28 09:53:01 siashcsitd03674 audit: PROCTITLE proctitle="bash"
Jun 28 09:53:01 siashcsitd03674 audit[19057]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=55ebd8827930 a1=55ebd88246f0 a2=55ebd8827d60 a3=8 items=2 ppid=31150 pid=19057 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0
Jun 28 09:53:01 siashcsitd03674 audit: EXECVE argc=2 a0="journalctl" a1="-xe"
Jun 28 09:53:01 siashcsitd03674 audit: CWD cwd="/"
Jun 28 09:53:01 siashcsitd03674 audit: PATH item=0 name="/bin/journalctl" inode=625 dev=fc:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 c
Jun 28 09:53:01 siashcsitd03674 audit: PATH item=1 name="/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" inode=3417 dev=fc:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=00000000000000
Jun 28 09:53:01 siashcsitd03674 audit: PROCTITLE proctitle=6A6F75726E616C63746C002D7865
```

Comment: `mysql` is the client, your error messages state thar you need to install  the server packages: `mysql-server-5.7` and `mysql-server`.

Comment: How do I install the server? Do I not use apt install mysql-server? This is the command I used to report an error.

Comment: You can `sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-server-5.7`.

Comment: Still prompt the same question